# communication between silverlight plugin and mvc project without using WCF

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller, webcam

I just need a help regarding the communication between the silverlight plugin which uses webcam and gives response to the mvc application.I just need the breakpoints to be hitted on the silverlight project run mode that are not hitting for the moment.

Any help will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **Solution Explorer** of *Visual Studio* right click on your web project and select **Properties**. Go to the **Web** tab. In the bottom under **Debuggers** check **Silverlight** checkbox. After that you can debug your Silverlight application.